# What is the best way to retrieve records from tables in multiple SQL Server schemas in one result set?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, say you have multiple tables with identical definitions (though not identical data), each in a different schema and owned by a separate SQL Server User:

schema1.People

schema2.People

schema3.People

...

What would be the best design to giving another user (in the generic sense of using the database, not necessarily a SQL Server User object) who has access to an arbitrary subset of those schemas a single list of all People in all schemas he has access to?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view, say AllPeople, which is a union of the three schema's tables perhaps.

Not sure if I understand correctly though. If you are looking for a dynamic method, this obviously won't work.

But if not, you could say

```
create view AllPeople as
select * from schema1.people
union
select * from schema2.people
union
select * from schema3.people
```

Of course, whoever creates the view and whoever reads the view would need to have adequate privs to do this.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of something dynamic, as the number of schemas is arbitrary and may be in the hundreds, though it would not be changing frequently. Two questions: (1) so you are saying that if a user had permissions to schema1 and schema2 but not schema3, this would work as expected without some sort of erro? (2) what are the performance ramifications of doing a bunch of unions in a view like this?

Comment: The question may probably have to do with working around error messages about certain tables being inaccessible due to insufficient rights.

Comment: That is correct. If you attempt to have a static view union-ing all of the {schema}.People tables, and the current user does not have permissions to select from all of the tables, you get a "The SELECT permission was denied on the object..." error for the inaccessible schemas.